# Reload Parent's Parent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do we reload parent's parent in JavaScript?

I tried the following code but it didn't seem to work:

```
<script>
    function closeOnRejectSuccess(){
        window.opener.parent.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: are the frame, the parent and the new window under the same domain ? If any is on a different domain, then you cannot communicate between them due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Yuo may try this:

```
function closeOnRejectSuccess(){
    window.opener.opener.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: @SanTosh:- What is your opener(is it a frame or what)?

Comment: its the parent -> iframe -> popup(opens from iframe)

Comment: @SanTosh:- You may try this: `parent.parent.document.getElementById('iframeid').location.reload();`

Comment: @SanTosh:- Hope you have used the correct `iframeid`?

Comment: @SanTosh:- Strange but as a last resort you may use `parent.location.href=parent.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the relationship is, either what you have (if your opener is a frame) or

```
window.opener.opener.location.reload();
//           ^^^^^^^
```

...if it's also been opened.